# Recent documents for currently logged in user (Client side)

Tags: javascript, search, rest, ootb

I want to achieve something like shown in Image below. I want to display Recent Document visited by logged in user.

I have tried it using Content Search Web-Part. I also tried to achieve it using Search API.

With the help of Content Search Web-Part, I got the result displaying recently viewed documents but it did not displayed results w.r.t. logged in user.

Can this be achieved using REST API? Are there any other Client Side method to achieve this?

```
<Site Url>/_api/search/query?querytext='path:<Site URL>/TestDocLibrary IsDocument:true'&sortlist='ViewsRecent:descending'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Friends Finally i manage my task I Got the Solution for my Question, As per my requirment I need to display Recent View Doc by logged in User From Sharepoint Online.To Get this result i used GRAPH Query+Search api, you can get more Exposure about GQL
[Graph Query Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/query-Office-graph-using-gql-with-search-rest-api)
Here is MY Query

> //Graph Query with Search api to get Recentview Document By Logged in User it will Return data From all Site Collection of tenent

```
var query = "/_api/search/query?QueryText='(*) AND (FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:xlsm OR FileExtension:pdf)'&Properties='TitleBasedSummaries:true,GraphQuery:actor(me\\,action\\:1001),GraphRankingModel:action\\:1001\\,weight\\:1\\,edgeFunc\\:time\\,mergeFunc\\:max'&SelectProperties='Author,AuthorOwsUser,DocId,DocumentPreviewMetadata,Edges,EditorOwsUser,FileExtension,FileType,HitHighlightedProperties,HitHighlightedSummary,LastModifiedTime,LikeCountLifetime,ListID,ListItemID,OriginalPath,Path,Rank,SPWebUrl,SecondaryFileExtension,ServerRedirectedURL,SiteTitle,Title,ViewCountLifetime,siteID,uniqueID,webID'&RowLimit=6&StartRow=0&ClientType='PulseWeb'&BypassResultTypes=true&RankingModelId='0c77ded8-c3ef-466d-929d-905670ea1d72'";
```

I will Share Full Code soon
Thanks

Comment: Note that GQL is about to be deprecated in favor of Microsoft Graph API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/query-Office-graph-using-gql-with-search-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no out of box solution that will provide you with the "Most Visited" documents that you would like.

You can try to create a custom solution to pull the information that you would like and display it in a web part.

Below I am including some links to resources that you can use in an attempt to create a custom solution that you desire.

- [Most viewed documents in SharePoint 2010](http://blogbaris.blogspot.in/2011/05/most-viewed-documents-in-sharepoint.html)
- [My Recent Documents-CodePlex](http://myrecentdocuments.codeplex.com/)
- [View the Most Popular Items report for a catalog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/28/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx#ViewMPI)